# Are function spaces over a shrinking set vector bundles?

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, filtrations, function-spaces

I have function spaces $F(S_t) \subseteq \{f : S_t \to \mathbb{R}\}$ defined over shrinking sets $S_t\subset S_s$ for $t> s$. I have a trivial fiber bundle $[0,\infty) \times F(S_0)$ where the projection map is $\pi((t,f)) = t$. I now consider the subbundle where at each $t$ I instead take the space $F(S_t)$. In order for this to be a fiber bundle I need a homeomorphism $\varphi : \pi^{-1}((a,b)) \to (a,b) \times H$ that locally trivializes the bundle and the projection from $(a,b)\times H$ agrees with $\pi$. My issue is finding a homeomorphism $\varphi$. For example if I were to take $H = F(S_a)$ then I could extend any function $f \in F(S_t)$ for $t\in (a,b)$ to a function from $F(S_a)$ by setting it to zero outside of $S_t$. In that case $\varphi$ would be injective, but not surjective. On the other hand if I were to take $H = F(S_b)$ and map any function $f\in F(S_t)$ to $F(S_b)$ by its restriction to $S_b$ then the map is not injective. So my conclusion was that this is not a fiber bundle. Is there some other notion that generalizes fiber bundles that would allow for e.g. the case where $\varphi$ is not surjective? I am looking for some reference that formalizes the above in a similar way as is done for fiber bundles. This arose from looking at PDEs with a shrinking domain due to a contracting boundary.

Comment: I haven't read the whole question, but I'm guessing "shrinking" is a translation of a word that should be translated as "contractable"?

Comment: @JonathanZ I just have a sequence of nested sets $S_t \subset S_s$ for $t > s$. Those also happen to be Lebesgue measurable and the measure of those happens to be differentiable w.r.t. time, but I wasn't sure how relevant that was to the question. $F$ can also be assumed to be nice, e.g. $L_2$ or $C^k_b$. My bigger issue is finding any resources on such a construct where the spaces are parametrized by time and their domain shrinks with time, since I can't seem to make this a fiber bundle, which I felt would have been the closest construct here.

Comment: Oh, you have a (real-) parameterized family of set, and they get smaller as the parameter increases! I got confused, thinking that "shrinking" applied to each individual set, and not to the family. Please ignore my comment.